# How to increase performance of Angular Material, or how to find out what makes it slow?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

This is a simple snapshot of our menu (tab) in our angular application, that uses Material Design.

[image]

As you can see, it's very very slow, and the click wave takes too long to show, and it's not gradual and transitional anymore. It's abrupt and sudden. Also, the underline of tabs won't move smoothly and immediately. This is everywhere.

What makes Angular Material so slow, or what checklist should we use or what possible debugging approaches should we use to find out the problem?

Comment: Are you loading lot of data on tab click? If not then may be you can try disabling the material themes to check if themes are behind this performance issues

Comment: How do you know is the angular material code making it slow? What debugging have to done?